# Router with Dynamic IP Address - How to point it to my domain. For my CCTV

Tags: internet-connection, wireless-router, dynamic-ip, cctv

I have CCTV in my office and port-forward its ip to router. my router ip is dynamic how can i access my CCTV with my own domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look in your router's setup for using a dynamic dns service such as DynDNS (http://dyn.com/dns/) or no-ip (www.no-ip.com/).

These sort of services provide you with a domain name and your router then updates their DNS records with your current ip address.